# AjaxControlToolkit reference in VS2010 with .NET 2.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-2.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a strange problem when attempting to compile an old website which is hamstrung with .NET 2.0 and VS2010.

I've installed ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 and I have the AjaxControlToolkit binary referenced in the project, both resolve just fine and appear in the Object Browser. Code highlighter also shows their presence is detected.

However, when I try to compile, AjaxControlToolkit disappears from the Object Browser and I get a whole bunch of "'AjaxControlToolkit' is not declared" errors. I have to reload the solution in VS for it to reappear in the Object Browser.

The AjaxControlToolkit reference has the following attributes:

```
Description: Ajax Control Toolkit
Identity: AjaxControlToolkit
Resolved: True
Runtime Version: v2.0.50727
Specific Version: False
Strong Name: True
Version: 1.0.11119.25055
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you open the bin in object explorer, do you see the DLL there?  Sometimes I've had reference errors when I reference the AjaxControlToolkit from a location other than the bin folder.

Comment: Afraid so. It wasn't the DLL I was referencing, but it is an exact copy of it, and if I change the reference to point to that one instead, there's no change in behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe I missed this (well, okay, the message only showed up after trying to recompile a zillion times and deleting/changing files), but there was a warning about being unable to resolve a reference to System.Web.Extensions.Design -- the project didn't have a reference to this despite having a reference to System.Web.Extensions and being compileable before.

After re-adding the reference, the website compiles. They should really promote that warning to an error!

Comment: A future word of warning though - Norton doesn't like AjaxControlToolkit.dll for some reason, and tried to remove it. Yes, I know, why would Norton be on a development machine.